# App level kotlin function in android project

Tags: android, kotlin

Can anybody explain how I can release an app-level kotlin function in Android Studio project? I have an Android application and I try do someting like this:

```
        var date: Date = Date()

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // this block must be app-level fun
        val format = “dd.MM.yyyy”
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(format)
        var formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

convert Date object to String with custom format. I do it many times (in different activities and fragments) in my project, so I think it will be good idea to releas this code as function (or class, if it will be more efficient). Thus I have date and format as input parameters and formattedDate as output. Also it will be good to set default format value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extension function on `Date` that accepts a format and uses it to convert the date to that format. You can also define the default format on the input parameter. Something like:

```
fun Date.toFormattedString(format: String = "dd.MM.yyyy"): String {      
  val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(format)
  return simpleDateFormat.format(this)
}
```

Place it in a file where the whole app can access it (e.g., a file named Extensions.kt in a module/package where you put all reusable and/or helper code) and then just use the function like `someDate.toFormattedString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of my function contained in separate kotlin file called Time.kt

```
fun timeConverter(string: String?, i: Int): String {
    val isoFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    var expectedFormat = "dd/MM"
    when(i){
        0 -> expectedFormat = "dd/MM"
        1 -> expectedFormat = "EEE"
        2 -> expectedFormat = "HH:mm"
        3 -> expectedFormat = "EEE, dd/MM"
    }
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(isoFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    val date = dateFormat.parse(string)
    return SimpleDateFormat(expectedFormat).format(date)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the function part of an object.

https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-objects

Objects (not class) in Kotlin are static. If you import the object from where you use the function, it can be used anywhere without being instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a DateUtil `class` that holds a format `function` as `companion`. You will be able to use it anywhere in your app without instantiating it.

```
class DateUtil{
    companion object {
        fun format(date: Date):String{
            val format = "dd.MM.yyyy"
            val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(format)
            return  simpleDateFormat.format(date)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call it: `DateUtil.format(Date())`